# Enable both Windows Auth and username/password login in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, windows-authentication, httpcontext

I have an application that I want both

- A username/password entered (which has to be an AD account)
- A button that allows us to Sign In using our AD account

The reason I need both is there are cases I want to login with another user in the domain (it is just a dummy testing account and not another person in the domain).

In the project settings, I enable Windows Auth which then the HttpContext.User will be the Windows User on the device. If they click the "Sign in with AD", it will just use this account and proceed.

If I enter the user/pass, it will use LDAP and attempt to Bind and if the creds are successful, I will do a HttpContext.SignInAsync()

The issue arises when I logout. If I reroute to any [Authorize] controller, the HttpContext.User will default to the Windows account which isn't correct.

It seems there is not really a way to work around this.
Say the flow is

- Login GET
- Login POST
- Welcome GET
- Logout GET
- Welcome GET (manually typing localhost:PORT/Home/Welcome). This is the issue since it will default to the Windows Authentication user (the HttpContext.User).

// Startup enables CookiesAuth
[image]

// Login GET

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View(new LoginViewModel());
    }
```

// Login POST

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // This will check the LDAP to see if the user is in the domain
        if (ModelState.IsValid && await ValidateUser(viewModel.Username, viewModel.Password))
        {
            User user = null;

            // TODO
            // VALIDATE IF USER IS IN DB, OTHERWISE ADD THEM HERE.

            user = new User()
            {
                RoleId = 1,
                Username = viewModel.Username!
            };

            var claims = new[] {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.RoleId.ToString())
            };

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync
                (CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
                new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), 
                new AuthenticationProperties());

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Welcome));
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid credentials");
        viewModel.Password = string.Empty;
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Logout GET

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
    }
```

Comment: If it is only about testing and not a regular use case, you could just implement plain windows authentication and run the browser under another user account when testing. This would save you some work and also reduce the risk of security issues because your authentication/authorization implementation is simpler.

Comment: @Markus but that's the issue - if I implement regular Windows Auth, I have the HttpContext.User always set to the AD of the device when logged out.

Comment: IIS/ASP.NET was designed to support only one of the two at a time, so don't waste your time on that. You cannot log out a user if he/she logged in via IIS Windows authentication.

Comment: @LexLi so the User that is attached to the HttpContext will always return the Windows Account of the station if Windows Authentication is enabled on my app? I'm guessing the best thing then would be to just have a user/password and drop the "Sign with AD" and use Anonymous. The user would have to be in the domain anyways so allow since we use LDAP to verify the account but got flexibility of logging in with different accounts, the username/password is sufficient. If I disable Windows Auth then, is there any way to get the workstation domain User another way on the HttpRequest?

Comment: If switching login users is your key goal, then IIS anonymous + ASP.NET forms authentication with AD accounts provider is your only feasible solution. I think you already knew that. However, a disadvantage of this approach is that you lose auto-login feature of IIS Windows authentication, and there isn't a way to know the workstation domain user until he/she fills in the login form.

Comment: If you implement plain WinAuth the browser transmits the logged in user. By default, this is the account you work with. But you can also start the browser with a different user: Hold Shift, right click on the browser, select " Run as a different user" and log in. In this case a session for the other user is created and the browser runs as the other account. No need for login buttons in the app etc.

Comment: I guess the solution will be to just use a user/pass combo and drop the AD login button. This will give flexibility to both scenarios where we want to test any account